# L2 Boosting in R

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I'm coding a toy implementation of L2 Boosting (page 13 of https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1207580163) in pure R, just for didatic reasons.

Since, I had problems with the code, I wrote this particular case that works fine:

```
library(MASS)

set.seed(1234)

idx <- sample(1:nrow(Boston), size = round(0.5*nrow(Boston)), replace = FALSE)
training <- Boston[idx,]
test <- Boston[-idx,]

library(tree)

lambda <- 0.01
B <- 3
psi <- vector("list", B)
g <- vector("list", B)
res <- vector("list", B)

X <- subset(training, select = -medv)

psi_0 <- function(x) rep(mean(training$medv), nrow(training))

medv <- training$medv - psi_0(X)
res[[1]] <- cbind(X, medv)
g[[1]] <- function(x) predict(tree(medv ~ ., res[[1]]), x)
psi[[1]] <- function(x) psi_0(x) + lambda * g[[1]](x)

medv <- training$medv - psi[[1]](X)
res[[2]] <- cbind(X, medv)
g[[2]] <- function(x) predict(tree(medv ~ ., res[[2]]), x)
psi[[2]] <- function(x) psi[[1]](x) + lambda * g[[2]](x)

medv <- training$medv - psi[[2]](X)
res[[3]] <- cbind(X, medv)
g[[3]] <- function(x) predict(tree(medv ~ ., res[[3]]), x)
psi[[3]] <- function(x) psi[[2]](x) + lambda * g[[3]](x)

psi[[3]](test)
```

**[ Warning: the following code will crash your R session. ]**

But, if I try to write a more general version of it with a loop, like this:

```
library(MASS)

set.seed(1234)

idx <- sample(1:nrow(Boston), size = round(0.5*nrow(Boston)), replace = FALSE)
training <- Boston[idx,]
test <- Boston[-idx,]

library(tree)

lambda <- 0.01
B <- 3
psi <- vector("list", B)
g <- vector("list", B)
res <- vector("list", B)

X <- subset(training, select = -medv)

psi_0 <- function(x) rep(mean(training$medv), nrow(training))

for (b in 1:B) {
    if (b == 1) {
        medv <- training$medv - psi_0(X)
        res[[1]] <- cbind(X, medv)
        g[[1]] <- function(x) predict(tree(medv ~ ., res[[1]]), x)
        psi[[1]] <- function(x) psi_0(x) + lambda * g[[1]](x)
    } else {
        medv <- training$medv - psi[[b-1]](X)
        res[[b]] <- cbind(X, medv)
        g[[b]] <- function(x) predict(tree(medv ~ ., res[[b]]), x)
        psi[[b]] <- function(x) psi[[b-1]](x) + lambda * g[[b]](x)
    }
}

psi[[B]](test)
```

I get the error

**Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)? Error during wrapup: Error during wrapup: Error during wrapup: ...**

and the session is aborted. As pointed out by Ben in the comments, this is probably related to the way lazy evaluation is handled in R.

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: lazy evaluation.  You may need a `force(b)` somewhere, e.g. `psi[[b]] <- function(x) psi[[force(b)-1]](x) + lambda*predict(tree,x)`

Comment: Thank you, Ben. I still can't make it work. I will add more details to the question.

Comment: Sorry, @Gregor! Fixed. Thanks.